# Appium: How can I located RecyclerView to locate an Element

Tags: java, appium-android

I am unable to locate Recycler view using Appium

[image: Screenshot]

When I try to locate the `RecyclerView`, the Appium server just halts. In this image (`ListView`) I want to check the checkbox which is highlighted in the image.

The approach I am using is `findingElementbyid("Recyclerview")` get its index and click on checkbox.

Can you please guide the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need not find the recyclerView. You can do the following

@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@text='Primary Account']")
private List primaryAccounts;

or

@AndroidFindBy(id= "com.ezepay:id/bMakePrimary")
private List primaryAccounts;

Then, in order to click on a particular button, you can do the following
click(primaryAccounts.get(index));

Comment: Thanks. 
Could you please elaborate on private List and primaryAccounts?

Comment: Your intention to click on the Primary Account checkbox. So, `@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@text='Primary Account']") private List<MobileElement> primaryAccount`; will return list of Primary Account checkbox available on the recyclerview. Once you have the list, you can click on any particular checkbox using it's index

Comment: Thanks. 
Where do I need to use this? 
I get the error @AndroidFindBy is disallowed for this location.
How to perform click action as well? 

I am sorry, I am very new to this and I am stuck at listView for finding elements

Comment: **Here is my code**
I am unable to post my entire snippet as there is a character limit from StackOverflow
   @Test(priority = 5)
     public void testSelectingPrimaryAccount() throws InterruptedException {
      @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@text='Primary Account']") private List<MobileElement> primaryAccount;
    

I am placing the above code after the execution of the login, adding a bank account and the screen which you can see above. 
Thank you

Comment: You need to declare the 
`@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@text='Primary Account']")`
`private List<MobileElement> primaryAccounts`;

outside the test method.

Comment: If I declare outside the test Method
How can I perform the action in the flow? 
Here, how do I say Appium to click on that checkbox which I want to click? 
Can you please explain?

Comment: Can you try the below

Comment: `List<MobileElement> primaryAccount = appiumDriver.findElements(By.id("com.ezepay:id/bMakePrimary"))'

In order to click on a particular element
`primaryAccount.get(index).click();`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Shrirang.
Unfortunately, it is not working, I tried in all possible ways. 
I am unable to locate the locator. I used the tap gesture, it is working fine for now. But, it is a bad approach. Unsure, how to do this.
Need to see, if anyone else faced this issue